# Direct Access steps

Tags: windows-server-2008

I wondering if there is any decent step by step Direct Access documentation out there?. Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Are you talking about this? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/network/dd420463.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think that you wont need a step by step for Direct Access, the Configuration Wizards show you the steps really simple.
But i will recommend you [this Step by Step](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24144) from Microsoft, it is exactly what you have to do in a laboratory enviroment. Off course you have to change the names and IPs to suit to your network.

Regards